# In CrafterCMS 3, how do I create a filter?

Tags: crafter-cms

The docs mention `site.xml` and a config snippet with `<site>` on the root, but `site.xml` seems to no longer exist, and there's no config with `<site>` at its root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In version 3.0, you'll have the ability to edit the site.xml directly from Studio from SiteConfig > Configurations > Engine.

These are the two tickets where this is being developed:
https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/860
https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/859